# Items in ListView disappear after I setItems in ListView - Java

Tags: listview, javafx

First time to use stack overflow.
I am very new to JavaFx. I have a ListView in my project to show all the **Post** items.There has three kind of Post which are **Event**, **Sale** and **Job**. When I'm trying to use a **ChoiceBox** to filter Post and display different kind of Post. I find it work well in the first few runs. After I change choice box serval times items disappear but I can still choose item on ListView. I found FilteredList is correct after I print it. It looks like items on ListView doesn't load very well.

Here is the code of initialise setting

```
postInfoObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(UniLinkDatabase.getPosts().values());

        //set choice box items
        typeChoiceBox.getItems().addAll("All", "Event", "Sale", "Job");
        typeChoiceBox.setValue("All");
        statusChoiceBox.getItems().addAll("All", "Open", "Closed");
        statusChoiceBox.setValue("All");
        creatorChoiceBox.getItems().addAll("All", "My Post");
        creatorChoiceBox.setValue("All");

        //set ListView items
        postInfoListView.setItems(postInfoObservableList);
        postInfoListView.setCellFactory(listView -> new PostListViewCellController(currentUserIDLabel.getText()));

        //turn off selection mode
        postInfoListView.setFocusTraversable(false);

        FilteredList<Post> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(postInfoObservableList, p -> true);

        typeChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(post -> {
                if (newValue == "Event" && post instanceof Event) {
                    return true;
                } else if (newValue == "Sale" && post instanceof Sale) {
                    return true;
                } else if (newValue == "Job" && post instanceof Job) {
                    return true;
                } else if (newValue == "All") {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
            postInfoListView.setItems(filteredData);
        });
```

The code for override updateItem

```
    protected void updateItem(Post post, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(post, empty);
        if(empty || post ==null){
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
        else {
            if(mlLoader == null){
                mlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/post_listView_cell.fxml"));
                mlLoader.setController(this);
                try {
                    mlLoader.load();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //set common details of post
                titleLabel.setText(post.getTitle());
                postIDLabel.setText(post.getId());
                creatorIDLabel.setText(post.getCreatorId());
                statusLabel.setText(post.getStatus());
                descriptionLabel.setText(post.getDescription());

                postImageView.setImage(post.getPhoto());

                //set other details according the types of post
                if(post instanceof Event){
                    hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: LIGHTCYAN ");
                    label00.setText("Venue:");
                    label01.setText("Date:");
                    label02.setText("Capacity:");
                    label03.setText("Attendee count:");

                    label10.setText(((Event) post).getVenue());
                    label11.setText(((Event) post).getDate());
                    label12.setText(Integer.toString(((Event) post).getCapacity()));
                    label13.setText(Integer.toString(((Event) post).getAttendeeCount()));
                }else if(post instanceof Sale){
                    hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: LIGHTPINK ");
                    label00.setText("Highest offer:");
                    label01.setText("Minimum raise:");

                    label10.setText("$"+ ((Sale) post).getHighestOffer());
                    label11.setText("$"+ ((Sale) post).getMinRaise());

                    //Check information about current user to decide show Asking price or not
                    if(currentUserID.equalsIgnoreCase(post.getCreatorId())){
                        label02.setText("Asking price:");
                        label12.setText("$"+ ((Sale) post).getAskingPrice());
                    }
                }else if(post instanceof Job){
                    hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: LIGHTYELLOW ");
                    label00.setText("Proposed price:");
                    label01.setText("Lowest offer:");

                    label10.setText("$" + ((Job) post).getProposedPrice());
                    label11.setText("$"+ ((Job) post).getLowestOffer());
                }

                setText(null);
                setGraphic(hbox);
                //TODO recognize different post

            }
        }
    }
```

It work well at first time to load 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JypIt.png)
But after change choiceBox few times it miss some post, But still can choose item on ListView[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7XZ1.png)

Doesn't anyone know what the problem it is?

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing ;) [mcve] please ..

Comment: You have all your set-the-graphic code inside an `if (mlLoader == null)` block. That means it will only execute the first time, when `mlLoader` is null. The second and subsequent times that field won't be null and the code won't execute. You probably want to simply move your if/else-if + `setGraphic(...)` stuff to just _after_ the `if (mlLoader == null)` block.